# oracle database - insert into table having unique key constraint shows 1 row(s) inserted when the value is actually duplicate. - happens in a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a simple table with 2 columns col1 is a number and col2 is an email. Col1 is a pk and is populated through a sequence and i have a unique key constraint on col2. the code looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE  "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5" 
   (    "PKCOL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100), 
     CONSTRAINT "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PKCOL")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "UNIQUE_EMAIL" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )
/

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "BI_LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5" 
  before insert on "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5"               
  for each row  
begin   
  if :NEW."PKCOL" is null then 
    select "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5_SEQ1".nextval into :NEW."PKCOL" from sys.dual; 
  end if; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5" ENABLE
/
```

I insert an email id into this table say abc@def.com and this succeeds.

```
Insert into LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 (email) values (abc@def.com);

1 row(s) inserted.
```

I have a function which will ask the user to provide the email id and store it in a bind variable. this function checks if the value in the bind variable already exists in the table or not. If yes, gives a output as 'email already exists' if the bind variable value is not there in the db, inserts the value into the table.

When i run this function and provide any existing email to the bind variable, i see result as follows:
email already exists
1 row(s) inserted.

Code looks like follows:

```
declare
v_email varchar2(100);
begin

BEGIN
    select email into v_email from LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 where email = :EMAIL;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        v_email := null;
END;
    if (v_email is null) then
    Insert into LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 (email) values (:EMAIL);
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('email already exists');
    end if;
end;

output of this function is :
email already exists

1 row(s) inserted.
```

Please help me where i am going wrong in this function. Why do i see 1 row inserted? I was expecting to get unique key violation error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just put a unique constraint on the `email` column to prevent duplicate e-mail addresses.

Comment: I failed to reproduce the behavior you describe, using Oracle Database 18c Express Edition on Windows 10.

Comment: By the way, it's best to avoid double-quoted names unless you *really* need them. You could have some typo like a space instead of an underscore or mixed case, and the CREATE would succeed and you'd only find out about it later when some code didn't compile or gave wrong results etc.

Comment: Also, if you made the trigger `for each row when (new.pkcol is null)` you wouldn't need the `if` check, and you don't need to `select from dual` as you can just assign the value directly as `:new.pkcol := listofpeopletoviewpage5_seq1.nextval;` However, allowing a mixture of generated and manually entered values in a unique ID column is asking for trouble in my opinion. If a user enters a higher value than the current sequence value, it's a matter of time until the trigger fails with a unique constraint violation.

Comment: The output you're sowing from the PL/SQL code is not correct, in the sense that PL/SQL does not print the number of rows inserted; so please show the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your test case and can't reproduce what you are saying.

Sample table, sequence and trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE  "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5"
  2     (    "PKCOL" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
  3      "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(100),
  4       CONSTRAINT "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PKCOL")
  5    USING INDEX  ENABLE,
  6       CONSTRAINT "UNIQUE_EMAIL" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
  7    USING INDEX  ENABLE
  8     )
  9  /

Table created.

SQL> create sequence LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5_SEQ1;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5"
  2    before insert on "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5"
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :NEW."PKCOL" is null then
  6      select "LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5_SEQ1".nextval into :NEW."PKCOL" from sys.dual;
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> Insert into LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 (email) values ('abc@def.com');

1 row created.
```

Anonymous PL/SQL block (I use SQL*Plus and have changed `:EMAIL` to `'&&EMAIL'`, but that doesn't affect what you are reporting as a problem):

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_email varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    BEGIN
  5      select email into v_email from LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 where email = '&&EMAIL';
  6    EXCEPTION
  7      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  8        v_email := null;
  9    END;
 10
 11    if (v_email is null) then
 12       Insert into LISTOFPEOPLETOVIEWPAGE5 (email) values ('&&EMAIL');
 13    else
 14       dbms_output.put_line('email already exists');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /
Enter value for email: abc@def.com
email already exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From listofpeopletoviewpage5;

     PKCOL EMAIL
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 abc@def.com

SQL>
```